# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<alertDialogAction>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-alertdialog

I am trying to make a reusable `AlertDialog` in Dart and was able to make one. The UI displays and it works well. The only problem in this code is that when I press the Save Button, it gives the following error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'. Below is my `AlertDialog` class:

```
enum alertDialogAction { cancel, save }

class Dialogs {
  static Future<alertDialogAction> alertDialog(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    String body,
  ) {
    final action = showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            title: Text(title),
            content: Text(body),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.pop(context,alertDialogAction.cancel),
                  child: Text("cancel")),
              RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(alertDialogAction.save),
                  child: Text(
                    "save",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
    return (action != null) ? action : alertDialogAction.cancel;
  }
 }
```

Here is how I call it in my index.dart:

```
 final action=await Dialogs.alertDialog(context,"title", "body");
 if (action == alertDialogAction.save){
      //code runs
      }
```

Comment: I think your textDialog method returns Future<dynamic> type. But in your Dialog class, you're having alertDialog. This will return Future<AlertDialogAction> type and now compare the equality with alertDialogAction.save. Can you please update your question with textDialog method ?

Comment: @VinothVino Thank you for your reply, it seems that I copied the wrong code here. I copied my textDialog class's code. It is supposed to be await Dialogs.alertDialog. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are returning a `Future<dynamic>` by declaring `final action` meanwhile you specified the return type of the `static` function `alertDialog` to be `Future<alertDialogAction>`.

To avoid such a problem in the future, always give a specific type to all the variable you declare.

```
Future<alertDialogAction> action = showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            title: Text(title),
            content: Text(body),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.pop(context,alertDialogAction.cancel),
                  child: Text("cancel")),
              RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(alertDialogAction.save),
                  child: Text(
                    "save",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
```

And call as such

```
alertDialogAction action=await Dialogs.alertDialog(context,"title", "body");
```